# How to parse through ArrayList containing Labels and Div(html)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.Add(lbl_name1);
list.Add(lbl_rating1);
list.Add(lbl_releasedate1);
list.Add(div_movie1);
```

I have created a array list as mentioned above where i have added some Labels and one Div(HTML's),how to retrieve these items further,like for label i can use Object class and later i can cast it to Label class,but there is no Div class in c#,so how to do that,anyone ?

```
foreach (object obj in list)
{
     Label lbl = new Label();
     lbl=(Label)obj;
     lbl.Text= "Hello";
}
```

This is how i suppose i'll be casting object into label.let me know if i am doing it right too .

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Enumerable.OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
foreach (Label lbl in list.OfType<Label>)
{
}
```

I am not sure why you are using `ArrayList` a better alternative is generic [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: And for Div ? i mean if list is made up of not only labels ?

Comment: What is the type of `div_movie1` ? How you have defined it ?

Comment: <div id="div_movie1" runat="server"></div>

Answer (score 0):

For divs - you can use

```
HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
```

Comment: I guess you are coming from Java background, there is `Dictionary` class instead of `Map` in .Net framework.

Comment: yeah....then you can use Dictionary class & can store any thing. i have removed that map code.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Label`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class implements the [`ITextControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.itextcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface.  If your new custom `Div` class also implemented the `ITextControl` interface, you could case the list of objects to that interface and set the `Text` property.  Any additional custom classes you add the the `ArrayList` would need to implement it as well.  From the `ITextControl` link:

```
public class CustomTextControl : Control, ITextControl
{
    private string _text;

    public CustomTextControl() // change this to DivControl
    {
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return _text;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                _text = value;
            }
            else
            {
                _text = "No Value.";
            }
        }
    }

    // Provide the remaining code to implement a text control.
}
```

Then casting would look like this:

```
foreach (object obj in list)
{
     ITextControl text_control = (ITextControl)obj;
     text_control.Text= "Hello";
}
```